# Windows 10, 32 GB eMMC laptop: `Windows can't be installed on drive 0 partition 1.`

Tags: windows, boot, uefi

I bought a new Dell Inspiron that has a 32GB eMMC disk but wanted a clean install from a Microsoft Windows 10 ISO (not the Dell image).

I duly booted off a USB key with the latest ISO off MSDN and wiped all the partitions. When I recreated a partition and try to install Windows on it I get this error:

`Windows can't be installed on drive 0 partition 1.`

Clicking for details...

`Windows cannot be installed to this disk. This computer's hardware may not support booting to this disk. Ensure that the disk's controller is enabled in the computer's BIOS menu`

I tried enabling legacy mode in BIOS, UEFI again and using `diskpart` to toggle between `GPT` and `MBR` in various combinations - all to no avail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was I had built the bootable Windows USB using the wrong option in [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/).

I was reusing a USB Key I built a while ago but am reasonably certain it was built with

`MBR partition scheme for BIOS or UEFI computers`

When I rebuilt the USB key using

`GPT partition scheme for UEFI computer`

Windows Setup was able install to the eMMC disk.

[image]