# USB bootable drive preventing me to access BIOS

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, boot, bios

I have a Thomson-branded netbook that has a **microSD** card as **unique storage area**. The SD shows 58.xx GB of disposable space.
There was a Windows 10 instance I wanted to wipe in order to restaure my own windows10 acronis true image backup, however even though it was few MB less than the maximum, it couldn't manage to restaure. I acccessed the bios through 'Esc' key.

So I used a PopOS live-try bootable to use **`gparted` and wipe the SD card** (tried to format it "empty", MSDOS, and FAT32). However after that, I **was only able to boot on EFI shell** and type `exit` to access the BIOS, that did not show my Win10 bootable plugged in before the boot.

After  that I decided to **fresh install Kubuntu**, which suggested me to **install an EFI "system partition"** alongside the remainder for `/` the root partition. It went all good and I am able to boot on Kubuntu.

However now I'm only able to access the BIOS through spamming `Esc` **when** the win10bootable isn't plugged. **Whenever I try to boot with it plugged in, I'm stuck on the manufacturer (Thomson red logo) screen, and no BIOS shows up for me to choose the USB stick to boot on.**

Here is a **pic of the win10bootable content**, I believe it's not corrupted since it shows up flawlessly on an ubuntu16.04 system. **+ Another pic**ture **of what looks like my BIOS** when I access it without a bootable plugged, and after having flashed kubuntu :

[image]

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeEnB.jpg

What to do please? Regards

[edit] to answer @Madhubala,

- the win10 bootable works on another dualboot HP machine (its BIOS recognizes it)
- gparted isn't able to format partitions to gpt
- but I tried keeping the 100MiB partition `dev/mmcblk0p1` in fat32 (gparted flags are "boot, esp") and format `dev/mmcblk0p1` (gparted flag "msftdata") in ntfs : BIOS still not accessible and stuck on OEM screen.
- when formating the whole eMMC to ntfs, same freeze.

Would you have other hints ? regards

Comment: how did you create the win USB ?? Can you boot from that USB on other pc/laptop ??

Comment: and why formatting in MSDOS when there is UEFI support ?? Format it with gpt and ntfs filesystem instead

Comment: thank you for answering, I edited my post accordingly

Comment: make sure csm disabled ; use https://github.com/WoeUSB/WoeUSB to create win usb on linux ; "gparted isn't able to format partitions to gpt" - any reson , why ? ; see this https://superuser.com/questions/1293899/windows-10-32-gb-emmc-laptop-windows-cant-be-installed-on-drive-0-partition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try something like Ventoy (https://www.ventoy.net/en/index.html)
to install the OS. It does not care about BIOS and is always seen by
system during boot menu.